# Node Js Performance

Tags: node.js

Welcome ... I'm working with Node js and i have a problem *Performance Problem*
Is this code better ... From my point of view the first one not the best because it may takes time for searching about specific item

```
cart: {
    items: [{
        productId: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Product'
        },
        offerId: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Offer'
        },
        quantity: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        }
    }]
}
```

Or this

```
product_cart: {
    items: [{
        productId: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Product'
        },
        quantity: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        }
    }]
},
offer_cart: {
    items: [{
        offerId: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Offer'
        },
        quantity: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        }
    }]
},
```

Which of two codes are the best for performance ?

Comment: Well, your question is wrong. Nodejs does not have to do with this. All operation is done on MongoDB Side

Comment: Muhammad, you need to restructure your question. 1. Are you asking how to improve the performance of node js when you process this JSON in node js? 2. How to improve MongoDB schema for better performance?

Answer (score 2):

you are using mongodb schema in node js, 
`use this reference link:` https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

this document to schema setup very easy

Answer (score 0):

First of all your question is very generic. If the question is regarding on run-time preformance it depends on many factors not only the model schema. 
In any case you can use mongoose populate in order to access a specific field which your ObjectId is refering to. If this is your intention, You can read more aboute mongoose `populate()` here:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html